# How to display webpage in the webpage

Tags: asp.net

I am having two web pages `default.aspx` and `main.aspx`. How to show `main.aspx` content in `default.aspx`. i need to embed the content in one part of the `default.aspx`

Comment: Is it ok for you to do with jQuery.

Comment: This is what you are looking for [ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: java script i need and i do not want to use User Control

Comment: Why dont you want to use a userControl it's the "right way"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud change Main.aspx to a `usercontrol`(.ascx) then you can include it like this

```
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Main" Src="~/Controls/Main.ascx" %>

 <uc:Main id="main"  runat="server" />
```

Comment: I frames, i am using. Is there any better option ?

Comment: Well iframe is the worst options. Why wont you use a userControl? 
you can also change your default.aspx to a master page

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to embed the content in an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

So in default.apx, you should embed:

```
<iframe src="http://www.main.aspx"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You have some choices here:
1. Use iframe HTML tag
2. Use UserControl (.ascx)
3. Use MasterPage
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Load remote content into object element</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="siteloader"></div>​
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://tired.com/">');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[For more reference](http://api.jquery.com/load/)